# Java Custom Parser Like XML

Tags: java, regex, xml, saxparser

I have the `example.ftl` file with below content. I want to dynamically add a tag before or after the given tag like `xpath` (ex: `/data/userInformation/addressInfo/addressList/#list/address/City`) address. And want to replace the tagname or content.

If I use XML parser for this file I'm getting parsing exception.

```
<#assign payload = xml['child::node()']>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <userInformation>
        <userId>${payload.user.id}</userId>
        <userName>${payload.user.name}</userName>
        <userLanguage>${payload.user.@language}</userLanguage>
        <addressInfo>
            <addressList>
                <#list payload.addressList.address as addressItem>
                <address Type="${addressItem.@Type}">
                    <addressLine1>${addressItem.StreetNumber}</addressLine1>
                    <addressLine2>${addressItem.StreetName}</addressLine2>
                    <StreetType>${addressItem.StreetType}</StreetType>
                    <City>${addressItem.City}</City>
                    <State>${addressItem.State}</State>
                    <ZipCode>${addressItem.Zip}</ZipCode>
                </address>
                </#list>
            </addressList>
        </addressInfo>
    </userInformation>
</data>
```

Currently I'm trying with `StringUtils.substringBetween(content, "<"+tagName+">", "</"+tagName+">")` to get the specific content between a tag. But, this won't work for my requirement.

Could you please help what should be the better option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any good options for this.

1. The reason that XML parsers won't work is that Freemarker Template Language (FTL) is not valid XML.  You might be able to transform the FTL into XML (e.g. by rewriting `<#...>` to be an XML comment.   Then parse and transform the XML, and finally reverse the commenting transformation.
2. A text pattern matching / regex-based approach might work, but it is liable to be fragile.  Due to matches in the wrong context, for example.  The problem is that using pattern matching for parsing is exceedingly difficult ... for practical problems.
3. The final option is that FreeMarker (and its parser) are open source, so you could (in theory) modify it:

   a. You could make it do your transformations on the FreeMarker parse tree after it has been parsed, and before it is used.

   b. You could even do the above, and then unparse back to FTL.  (But as far as I can see, FreeMarker doesn't include an unparser ... so you would need to write one yourself.)
4. Use Javacc to implement your own FTL parser / transformer / unparser.  (You could start from the existing grammar; see https://github.com/apache/freemarker/blob/2.3-gae/src/main/javacc/FTL.jj.)

Of these, 4 is the cleanest, though you will have a substantial amount of custom code to develop and maintain.

Maybe the best approach would be to find a way to NOT have to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm using regex to use custom logic. Could you please suggest how to take element name alone in the specific node. Ex. If I use data, i want to get only userInformation. If I use data/userInformation, I want only userid, name, language, addressInfo. How is it possible?

Comment: That is too broad.   And a different question.  But the way to solve it will be to do multiple matches with different regexes to find the elements you want in the contexts that you want.